# Virtuemart and automatic import of a file in my database

Tags: php, excel, joomla, virtuemart

I would like to convert a text file to excel and then modify certain data inside the excel file and then import this new excel file to a database using PHP.

The contents of the excel file, for example, will be products and their prices and the modification will be on the prices. So the update of the products in the database and on the website will be automatic. I am planning to use Joomla with Virtuemart.

My question is this: will Virtuemart allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natively, VM does not support excel importing, though there may be tools available at the JED.  I've done a lot of it using [phpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) which gives me the flexibility to consider the format of the spreadsheet, as well as however I may happen to be using the VM products and custom fields.

I just found this link on the [VM Forums](https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=103157.0) that might help.  It's for earlier version of VM, I think, but it might provide a foundation to get started with.

Comment: Added a link to my answer for some work already done by someone.  We've had most success with phpExcel because of the extensive configuration possibilities of VM and some of our internal bridging.

Answer (score 0):

VirtueMart won't have this functionality out of the box. Look for extension called "CSVI VirtueMart". I don't think it works with Excel files but it works with CSV and allows you to set up column mapping and import products into VM.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You shall import the csv files through csv imporved component without problems ,you shall also run the automatic imports by setting up the cron job,csv improved component has the built in support for the cron job